# Как найти регулярным выражение JSON внутри скобок

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть в тексте строка
findMe.NOW(JSON)
и необходимо с помощью регулярного выражения найти и извлечь только значение внутри этих скобок, там допустим JSON строка, отбросив все остальное.

Comment: Банально `/findMe\.NOW\((.+?)\)/` =)

Comment: действительно, я не правильно со скобками работал в регулярке, Спасибо)

Comment: а вот в этом варианте он уже не сработает - если в самих скобках есть перенос строки <test>{hhk}.+>TWExT
<script>
<sc\>/6ript>
Text_trash findMe.NOW(
JSON
);
)} Trash_Text (FGDS_4)
</script>

Comment: Все работает. Вы о чем? Не понял.

Comment: если в скобках добавить перенос строки не сработает( - https://regex101.com/r/Hc2wwi/2

Comment: Вам бы желательно создавать вопросы более развернуто, а то хочу это, а не вот это, а тут вот так надо. Так не делается. `findMe\.NOW\(([^)]+)\)`

Comment: точно ^ символ начала строки) здесь вы правы, извиняюсь, изначально подумал что решение будет универсальным) оказывается есть хитрость

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю это подойдет:
`/findMe\.NOW\(([^)]+)\)/`

Answer (score -1):

```
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $str, $match);
```

Ищет вхождение в строку `$str` выражения в круглых скобках

Comment: Это прикол такой? А что если кроме `findMe.NOW(JSON)` будет еще рядышком `findMe.NOW(JSON);MyName(Alex)` или еще чего? И с чего вы вообще взяли, что там `php`?

Comment: да абсолютно верно) в этом варианте он найдет все скобки)

Comment: @Andrew `preg_match` вернет только 1 вхождение а не все скобки
@And почти 2 суток не спал, не внимателен был, согласен, мой косяк (касательно `php`), а касательно остального уже ответил